# python split() issue on whitespace, can someone explain?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

```
AA  vowel
AE  vowel
AH  vowel
AO  vowel
AW  vowel
AY  vowel
B   stop
CH  affricate
D   stop
DH  fricative
EH  vowel
ER  vowel
EY  vowel
F   fricative
G   stop
HH  aspirate
IH  vowel
IY  vowel
JH  affricate
K   stop
L   liquid
M   nasal
N   nasal
NG  nasal
OW  vowel
OY  vowel
P   stop
R   liquid
S   fricative
SH  fricative
T   stop
TH  fricative
UH  vowel
UW  vowel
V   fricative
W   semivowel
Y   semivowel
Z   fricative
ZH  fricative
```

This is the content in a file, I then separate them into lines and parse them. The problem is when I use `line.split()` or even `re.split(r'\t+', line)`, seeing that the whitespace in between them resemble a tab, I get a problem that it splits them into characters. Help please, I don't understand where I am going wrong.

code for split

```
try:
        datafile = open(filename,'r')
    except IOError:
        print('Could not open ' + filename)
        sys.exit()
        pass

    stypes = {}

    for line in datafile.readlines():
        if line:
            re.split(r'\t+', line)
            phone = line[0]
            type = line[1]
        print(line[0] + ' ' + line[1] + ' ' + line[2])
```

Comment: Show the actual code you use to do the split.

Comment: @MikeMüller added, anything wrong with it?

Comment: Have you opened the file using the correct charset?

Comment: Please show the whole thing, including opening your file and printing the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing the original line not the list with the split results. This should work better:

```
with open('mywords.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        res = line.split()
        print(res)
```

Output:

```
['AA', 'vowel']
['AE', 'vowel']
```

The [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-16) statement opens a file and will close it as soon as you dedent
to the level of `with`, i.e. `fobj` will only be open until you write more code
on the same level of `with` (or end your function or program there). 
This is called a context manager. The context is the indented lines below `with`.

Example:

```
with open('mywords.txt') as fobj:
    print('closed', fobj.closed)
print('closed', fobj.closed)
```

Output:

```
closed False
closed True
```

Comment: thank you, some how it slip my mind i was calling the wrong thing and thank you for showing me a different approach. Can you also enlighten me to the use of with vs try/except. How do i close the file with this method?

Comment: Added some explanation.